# How to map tinyint to c# byte using entityframework code first migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to map tinyint column to byte property in c#How to achieve this efficiently. I want to store the values null, 0 and 1 to the database column. Please find below my code. Can anyone help me whether the following is the right approach?

```
public enum TriState : byte
{
    Null = 0,
    True = 1,
    False =2
}

[NotMapped]
public TriState AuthorisationStatus { get; set; }

[Column("AuthorisationStatus")]
public byte AuthorisationStatusByte {
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToByte(AuthorisationStatus.ToString());
    }
    private set
    {
        AuthorisationStatus = EnumExtensions.ParseEnum<TriState>(value);
    }
}

public static T ParseEnum<T>(byte value)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value.ToString(), true);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to go via a string at all. Just use the explicit conversions:

```csharp
[Column("AuthorisationStatus")]
public byte AuthorisationStatusByte
{
    get { return (byte) AuthorisationStatus; }
    set { AuthorisationStatus = (TriState) value; }
}
```

(I'm assuming the column attribute is correct - I don't know about that side of things.)

Comment: Thank you. How about if it is byte? i.e nullable byte

Comment: @MukilDeepthi: Then you'd presumably want a nullable enum property as well... and you'd just add a `?` within each of the casts as well.